# Reverse Partial Match in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have tried to do the following reverse partial match lookup however this doesn't work in google sheets. Is there another method that will work there?

https://www.excelcampus.com/tips/reverse-partial-match-lookup-filter/

Answer (score 3):

Try the following formula for result including blank cells

```
=INDEX(IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A,JOIN("|",F2:F7))))
```

or this one to exclude blanks

```
=QUERY(INDEX(IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A499,JOIN("|",F2:F7)))), 
         "where Col1<>'' ",0)
```

[image]

Functions used:

- [`QUERY`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343)
- [`INDEX`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098242)
- [`IFERROR`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093304)
- [`REGEXEXTRACT3098244`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093364)

Comment: Unfortunately I get a #REF! using this formula.

Comment: You need to clear ALL cells under it for the formula to work.